# Can I Use mysql_real_connect to Connect to a Server Without Mentioning the Database Using MySQL/C?

Tags: c++, mysql, c

I'm working on a CGI application written using C++ with the C MySQL adapter. I'm trying to run a query on two databases, so I want to connect to a MySQL server without choosing a default database. Is this possible? I'm using `mysql_real_connect()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysql_real_connect()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html) can take a `NULL` parameter for the database paramter, and this selects the default. Just ensure that the user has no default database set.

Answer (score 1):

I must be missing the point of your question. Seems to me if you want to use two databases, you only need two MYSQL*, one for each DB, calling mysql_real_connect( ) on each and then proceeding normally from there, referring to one or the other MYSQL* as appropriate. Could that work, or am I completely confused?